# How to BUILD OpenSSL for Indy

Tags: delphi, openssl, indy, delphi-xe4, indy10

How can I build OpenSSL so I can statically link them for use with Indy 10.6 for Windows 32/64 platforms? Is there an in depth guide somewhere to compile without any VC++ dependencies? I heard that Indy needs custom OpenSSL code not the official one. Also what compiler to use? VS2010, VS11, VS13?

It would be nice if it came with .lib files like it does for iOS.

Answer (score 3):

Indy stopped using custom-built OpenSSL DLLs years ago and has been using official DLLs ever since.

However, Indy does not currently support static linking of OpenSSL on non-iOS platforms at this time (there is a TODO item for that, but don't expect it to be implemented anytime soon, unless someone else does it and submits the changes for inclusion in Indy).  Even if you could compile static .obj files for OpenSSL on Windows, it would still require some code changes inside of Indy's source to make use of those files.  You would have to make those changes manually (see this discussion: [How to statically link Indy SSL files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695855/)) until they are made in Indy natively at some future time.

The only reason Indy supports OpenSSL statically on iOS is because Apple does not allow OpenSSL to be used dynamically on iOS devices (it does in the iOS simulator, though).  Every other platform does allow OpenSSL to be loaded dynamically, and that is how OpenSSL is primarily designed to be used.

Comment: Well Eldos has a solution. But it costs $1500. So why is Windows excluded yet iOS isn't? Having dll's is less secure because of dll hooking attacks.. Here you don't mention that it cannot be done. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695855/how-to-statically-link-indy-ssl-files)

Comment: Again, Apple **requires** OpenSSL (and any other third-party library, for that matter) to be statically compiled into iOS apps, there is no option to use external libraries dynamically. That is the **only** reason Indy supports a static version of OpenSSL on iOS. No other platform (including the iOS simulator) has that restriction, so there has never been a need to support OpenSSL statically on any platforms before.

Comment: As for the [other discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695855), #2 and #4 mentioned in it (editing `IdCompilerDefines.inc` and `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders_static.pas` to recognize OpenSSL static libs on Windows) has not been natively implemented in Indy yet. But I did touch on that above when I said it would require code changes in Indy's source.

Comment: yea we know how HeartBleed affects OpenSSL. Indy implementation is unsafe, period!

Comment: Heartbleed has nothing to do with Indy, it is a bug inside of OpenSSL itself. All you have to do is deploy the latest OpenSSL DLLs with your Indy-based app and Heartbeat will not be a factor anymore. No code changes needed, no recompiling needed (except for iOS apps).

Comment: Why not use the Windows SSL implementation for SSL? When will that be added to Indy?

Comment: It is on the TODO list, but there is no ETA on it yet as I have never worked with that particular API before. Besides, that would only address Windows, but Indy supports use of OpenSSL on many other platforms.

Comment: CleverComponents HTTP doesn't need no DLL's and it uses SSL.. so this is a very bad argument.

Comment: AFAIK, Clever uses its own SSL/TLS implementation written from scratch. That is a major undertaking that Indy will not do anytime soon due to time and manpower, not to mention it subjects user apps to international import/export laws on embedded encryption code. Indy uses OpenSSL because it is widely available and widely supported on most platforms, and is easily updated when fixes are released without requiring user apps to be recompiled. Indy will start supporting Microsoft encryption APIs on Windows in a future release, but other platforms do not have native encryption APIs, thus OpenSSL.

Comment: It is not a "very bad argument", it is an intentional design decision for cross-platform support.