# TIdHTTP.Get() equivalent for HTTPS without requiring we supply SSL libraries?

Tags: delphi, indy, idhttp

Does Indy have an equivalent of `TIdHTTP.Get()` for use on `https://` URLs that doesn't require us to ship SSL libraries?

Or, must we use something like `System.Net.HttpClient` as shown in this sample:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Rio/en/RTL.HttpDownload_Sample

Comment: AFAIK does Indy indeed require some SSL DLL, while THTTPClient uses the OS support for that.

Comment: Indy does not implement SSL/TLS itself, it uses external libraries for that support. That being said, there is nothing stopping you from implementing your own (or finding a 3rd party) `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase` derived class that uses OS provided SSL/TLS APIs, like SChannel on Windows (which is on Indy's TODO list for a future release). You can use any SSL/TLS library you want, you just need a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase` derived class to use it with Indy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695855/how-to-statically-link-indy-ssl-files