# Dynamically linking OpenSSL on iOS simulator

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm trying to get OpenSSL working for the iOS simulator. I'm on Delphi 11.2.

I'm following the steps described in this post: [How to statically link Indy SSL files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695855/)

I have `libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib` and `libssl.1.0.0.dylib` files.

I have `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` in my `uses` and I'm trying to run the following code:

```
var path := TPath.GetDirectoryName(ParamStr(0));
IdOpenSSLSetLibPath(path);
```

The above works for macOS, but on the iOS simulator the compiler says `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath` is an undeclared identifier.

I find it strange that I get this, because I've updated Indy's `IdCompilerDefines.inc` files like mentioned in the linked post.

I've updated:
`Core/IdCompilerDefines.inc`, `Protocols/IdCompilerDefines.inc` and `System/IdCompilerDefines.inc` so they contain this:

```
{$IFDEF IOS}
  {$DEFINE HAS_getifaddrs}
  {$DEFINE USE_OPENSSL}

  // Support for 64-bit ARM iOS Simulator was added in Delphi 11.2
  // TODO: how to detect iOS Simulator in FPC? Does it support 64-bit ARM?
  {$IFDEF CPUARM}
    {$IFNDEF IOSSIMULATOR}
      // RLebeau: For iOS devices, OpenSSL cannot be used as an external library,
      // it must be statically linked into the app.  For the iOS simulator, this
      // is not true.  Users who want to use OpenSSL in iOS device apps will need
      // to add the static OpenSSL library to the project and then include the
      // IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders_static unit in their uses clause. It hooks up the
      // statically linked functions for the IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders unit to use...
      {$DEFINE STATICLOAD_OPENSSL}
    {$ENDIF}
  {$ENDIF}
{$ENDIF}
```

Taken from https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/blob/master/Lib/Core/IdCompilerDefines.inc#L1647.

Delphi doesn't gray out `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath` anymore now, but I still get an undeclared identifier error.

[image]

Could my problem maybe have something to do with the `TODO` comment in the snippet above, or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Indy should already enable `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath()` on all non-iOSDevice platforms, including iOS Simulator. It singles out only iOSDevice for static loading. If this is not working, that will have to be fixed. In any case, if you modify Indy, it is not enough to just update the `.inc` files, you have to recompile Indy as a whole (and don't just download the `.inc` files, make sure you download the whole project), and replace the pre-installed shipped version with your recompiled version. Have you done that? See the [Updating Indy](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/wiki/Updating-Indy) doc

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you very much! That looks very promising, I will try that out next week. Don't know how I was able to miss that page.

Comment: Fixed the `IdOpenSSLSetLibPath` problem using `Remy Lebeau`'s  instructions and the Indy wiki. I now get a 'could not load openssl library' exception, I think my dylib files might be wrong. Gonna look into it.